Gospel Parallels Following Matthean Order?
I will be preaching/teaching out of portions of Matthew over the next couple months, and so am tapping into the other Gospels for their elaboration of (seemingly) common events. Of course, the chronological sequences are debated among scholars. Accordingly, am trying to make my own assessments.
I have found various synopsis/parallels which primarily follow the Marcan/Lucan pericope ordering and rearranges Matthew to comport with such. These generally seem to derive from Aland's work, but it would be nice to also have a synopsis which follows the Matthean pericope ordering, to see what that yields.
So here's the question: Is anyone aware of a synopsis/parallels spreadsheet which follows a Matthean pericope ordering, which rearranges Mark and Luke to comport with such (as much as possible)?
I have Throckmorten's Gospel Parallels, which follows the Matthean ordering; however, it doesn't try very hard to fit Mark and Luke into such. For example, there are no Mark/Luke parallels listed for Matthew's "Jairus's Daughter and the Woman with a Hemorrhage" pericope (Matt. 9:18-26); instead the Mark/Luke versions of the event are listed two pages later, but without the corresponding Matthean parallel. Granted, Throckmorton does show these parallels in columns further to the right, but they are intermixed with doublets and other noise.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Joseph Tyson's Synoptic Abstract may get you what you are looking for. His work is more of a spreadsheet than a synopsis, but he includes the pericope sequence using Matthean order, again using Markan order, and again using Lukan order.
I've made my own tables in Excel -- here's an example if it's of interest:
(the pericope naming conventions are somewhat fungible)


I've also discovered that there was a loose insert in my copy of Bernard Orchard's Matthew, Luke, and Mark (1976) which gave me what I wanted. I've scanned such, but has anyone found a spreadsheet form of such?
